# How to completely remove Xserver from OpenBSD?

Tags: xorg, bsd, xserver, openbsd

I just installed OpenBSD 6.9 to study how it works.
I wanted to get the most minimal config possible, because I want to use it as a server.

During instalation I chose the option to not install Xserver, but I still have the /usr/X11R6 and /etc/X11 directories with X config and commands like startx. The only difference is that now, startx doesn't work. I tried installing on VirtualBox and on bare metal and both were the same.

What do I have to do in order to completely remove X from OpenBSD? And why is it still being installed in my machine even if I explicitly write "no" when prompted during installation?

My system:

- OpenBSD 6.9
- Intel Pentium G5400
- Nvidia 1050 ti.

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD installation uses different file sets => see [OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html) / File Sets

X11 installation is split into 4 file sets :

- xbase71.tgz : Base libraries and utilities for X11 (requires xshare71.tgz)
- xfont71.tgz : Fonts used by X11
- xserv71.tgz : X11's X servers
- xshare71.tgz : X11's man pages, locale settings and includes

During installation, you chose not to install `xserv71.tgz` (X servers) but you still have installed `xbase71.tgz` (`startx` command and others directories).

If you want to completely remove X from OpenBSD, during installation, remove every file set for X. But you should keep xbase71.tgz because some programs needs it to run correctly even if it's a non-X program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a OpenBSD developer, so I cannot give a clear answer. But some specific packages which you can add with the package command from OpenBSD (`pkg_add`), needs some X libraries or binaries.

As example when you want to add `vim` for the first time, then you have eight flavors:

```
$ pkg_info -d vim-8.2.3456-no_x11
Information for inst:vim-8.2.3456-no_x11
[REMOVED]

Flavors:
        gtk2       - build using the Gtk+2 toolkit
        gtk3       - build using the Gtk+3 toolkit (default)
        no_x11     - build without X11 support
        lua        - build with Lua support
        perl       - build with Perl support
        python     - build with Python support
        python3    - build with Python3 support
        ruby       - build with Ruby support
```

It's depends on the packages what you need. Also when you want install something from the port collections.

You can try the quick and dirty way and simple remove your mentioned directories. But I could be possible that some programs from the base system no longer works, because of missing dependencies.